# How to turn ordinal rankings to integer score?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am new to code and this may be a straightforward fix –

I have 3 columns in a dataset:

```
age_bridges.Deck_rating
age_bridges.Supstr_rating
age_bridges.Substr_rating
```

and the ratings are ordinal from failed, failing, ... good, excellent

I want to assign an integer of 1-6 from failed to excellent for each column, then assign a new column called "condition" which is the total of the three scores. Any suggestions?

Here's the input:

```
condition = age_bridges.Deck_rating, age_bridges.Superstr_rating, age_bridges.Substr_rating

print(condition)
```

output:

```
(Structure_id
 000021521-00101         Good
 000021521-00181         Good
 000021521-TMP20    Very Good
 000021525-00012         Good
 000021580-00092         Good
                      ...    
 DAPFORHOO000012         Good
 DAPFORHOO000013         Good
 DAPFORHOO000015         Good
 DAPFORHOO00005A         Good
 DAPTRABLI000011         Good
 Name: Deck_rating, Length: 34293, dtype: category
 Categories (11, object): [Failed < Failing < Critical < Serious ... Good < Very Good < Excellent < NA],
 Structure_id
 000021521-00101    Very Good
 000021521-00181         Good
 000021521-TMP20    Very Good
 000021525-00012         Good
 000021580-00092    Very Good
                      ...    
 DAPFORHOO000012         Good
 DAPFORHOO000013         Good
 DAPFORHOO000015         Good
 DAPFORHOO00005A         Good
 DAPTRABLI000011    Very Good
 Name: Superstr_rating, Length: 34293, dtype: category
 Categories (11, object): [Failed < Failing < Critical < Serious ... Good < Very Good < Excellent < NA],
 Structure_id
 000021521-00101       Very Good
 000021521-00181       Very Good
 000021521-TMP20       Very Good
 000021525-00012            Poor
 000021580-00092       Very Good
                        ...     
 DAPFORHOO000012            Good
 DAPFORHOO000013            Good
 DAPFORHOO000015            Good
 DAPFORHOO00005A    Satisfactory
 DAPTRABLI000011            Good
 Name: Substr_rating, Length: 34293, dtype: category
 Categories (11, object): [Failed < Failing < Critical < Serious ... Good < Very Good < Excellent < NA])
```

And here's a sample of my data:

```
                  District  Detour_Km  Toll Maintainer  Urban    Status  Year  \
Structure_id                                                                    
000021521-00101  District2        199  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  2005   
000021521-00181  District2        199  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  2005   
000021521-TMP20  District2        199  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  2012   
000021525-00012  District2        199  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  1950   
000021580-00092  District2          6  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  2004   
000021580-00093  District2          3  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  2005   
000021594-62598  District2          3  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  2017   
000021594-TMP06  District2          3  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  1950   
000021594-TMP07  District2        199  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  1950   
000021594-TMP08  District2        199  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  1950   
000021594-TMP09  District2        199  Free     Agency  Rural     Local  1950   
010600013603028  District1          8  Free      State  Rural  Arterial  1934   
010600013603131  District1         10  Free      State  Rural  Arterial  2018   
010600013603132  District1         10  Free      State  Rural  Arterial  2016   
010600013603133  District1         11  Free      State  Rural  Arterial  2016   
010600013603134  District1         11  Free      State  Rural  Arterial  2016   
010600013603135  District1         11  Free      State  Rural  Arterial  2016   
010600013603136  District1          8  Free      State  Rural  Arterial  2016   
010600013603137  District1          8  Free      State  Rural  Arterial  2016   
010600013604058  District1          2  Free      State  Rural  Arterial  1938   

                 Lanes_on  Lanes_under  AverageDaily  ... Length Width  \
Structure_id                                          ...                
000021521-00101         1            0             1  ...   31.4   4.3   
000021521-00181         1            0             1  ...   15.5   4.3   
000021521-TMP20         2            0           100  ...   10.1   8.4   
000021525-00012         1            0            80  ...   45.4   3.7   
000021580-00092         2            0           150  ...   25.0   7.3   
000021580-00093         2            0           150  ...   49.1   8.5   
000021594-62598         2            0            20  ...   15.2   7.7   
000021594-TMP06         2            0            10  ...   32.6   7.6   
000021594-TMP07         2            0            40  ...    9.8   7.6   
000021594-TMP08         2            0            40  ...   46.3   7.6   
000021594-TMP09         2            0            40  ...    9.4   7.5   
010600013603028         2            0          4400  ...   43.6  12.6   
010600013603131         2            0          5000  ...   91.4  11.6   
010600013603132         2            0          6000  ...   91.4  11.6   
010600013603133         2            0          5000  ...   45.7   9.6   
010600013603134         2            0          5000  ...   54.9   9.6   
010600013603135         2            0          5000  ...   54.9   9.6   
010600013603136         2            0          5000  ...  103.6   9.3   
010600013603137         2            0          5000  ...   51.8  11.6   
010600013604058         2            0          1980  ...   48.8  12.6   

                  Deck_rating Superstr_rating  Substr_rating  Rated_load  \
Structure_id                                                               
000021521-00101          Good       Very Good      Very Good        41.7   
000021521-00181          Good            Good      Very Good        41.7   
000021521-TMP20     Very Good       Very Good      Very Good        48.1   
000021525-00012          Good            Good           Poor        10.0   
000021580-00092          Good       Very Good      Very Good        37.2   
000021580-00093     Very Good       Very Good      Very Good        49.9   
000021594-62598          Good       Very Good      Very Good        35.4   
000021594-TMP06          Fair            Fair           Poor        10.9   
000021594-TMP07          Fair            Good   Satisfactory        29.0   
000021594-TMP08          Good    Satisfactory           Fair        28.1   
000021594-TMP09  Satisfactory    Satisfactory   Satisfactory        29.0   
010600013603028  Satisfactory    Satisfactory   Satisfactory        22.7   
010600013603131     Excellent            Good           Good        32.7   
010600013603132     Very Good       Very Good      Very Good        32.7   
010600013603133     Very Good       Very Good           Good        32.7   
010600013603134     Very Good       Very Good      Very Good        32.7   
010600013603135     Very Good       Very Good           Good        32.7   
010600013603136     Very Good       Very Good           Good        32.7   
010600013603137     Very Good       Very Good      Very Good        32.7   
010600013604058          Good            Good   Satisfactory        22.7   

                 Trucks_percent Scour_rating Future_traffic Age  
Structure_id                                                     
000021521-00101             0.0          Dry              1  15  
000021521-00181             0.0          Dry              1  15  
000021521-TMP20             0.0          Dry            150   8  
000021525-00012             0.0          Dry            120  70  
000021580-00092             4.0          Dry            200  16  
000021580-00093             4.0          Dry            200  15  
000021594-62598             0.0          Dry             25   3  
000021594-TMP06             0.0       Stable             15  70  
000021594-TMP07             0.0       Stable             50  70  
000021594-TMP08             0.0          Dry             50  70  
000021594-TMP09             0.0          Dry             50  70  
010600013603028            13.0      Unknown           6160  86  
010600013603131            50.0      Unknown              1   2  
010600013603132            13.0          Dry           6800   4  
010600013603133            14.0          Dry           6800   4  
010600013603134            14.0          Dry           6800   4  
010600013603135            14.0          Dry           6800   4  
010600013603136            13.0          Dry           6800   4  
010600013603137            13.0          Dry           6800   4  
010600013604058            19.0          Dry           2770  82  

[20 rows x 25 columns]
```

Comment: Please share a sample input dataframe with expected output. This would make it clear for us.

Comment: I have edited my question if that helps.

Comment: Could you provide us a sample of your input data? Just print a few lines of your dataframe using `print(age_bridges.head(20))`, copy that and paste it in your question

Comment: done it – thanks for your help

Comment: Since you seem to already have a `category` dtype, it would be as simple as `age_bridges.Deck_rating.cat.codes`

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 large approaches you can take for this:

- Use `.map` to transform your column values into a numerical representation
- Change your columns into a pd.Categorical Series

Set up data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

ordered_ratings = ["failed", "failing", "fine", "good", "excellent"]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ranking": np.random.choice(ordered_ratings, 10)
})

print(df)
     ranking
0  excellent
1     failed
2       good
3       good
4       good
5    failing
6       good
7       fine
8  excellent
9     failed
```

#### Map approach

The map approach provides a 1 to 1 way of exchanging values in a Series to new values. This can be easily done with a dictionary, where all you need are mappings of {old_value: new_value}

So first we'll need to create a dictionary that maps {"failed": 1, "failing": 2, ..., "excellent": 5}

```
ordered_ratings_mapper = {v: i for i, v in enumerate(ordered_ratings, 1)}
print(ordered_ratings_mapper)
{'failed': 1, 'failing': 2, 'fine': 3, 'good': 4, 'excellent': 5}

# now we use `.map` to transform the values from "ranking"
df["mapped_ratings"] = df["ranking"].map(ordered_ratings_mapper)

print(df)
     ranking  mapped_ratings
0  excellent               5
1     failed               1
2       good               4
3       good               4
4       good               4
5    failing               2
6       good               4
7       fine               3
8  excellent               5
9     failed               1
```

That worked fine!

#### pd.Categorical approach

An alternative to keep your rating names tied to their numeric ranking counterpart is to use Categorical Series. Essentially you can tell pandas that your values are actually numeric rankings, and that their string values are simply for viewing/reading purposes. This allows you to use the numeric values when you want, while also maintaining great performance of having a column with an integer dtype over an object dtype.

`pd.Categorical` takes the column in question, the unique values we expect to see in that column, and a boolen value to indicate if these unique values are ordered or not (in this case we are dealing with an ordered set of categories).

```
df["cat_ratings"] = pd.Categorical(df["ranking"], ordered_ratings, ordered=True)

print(df)

     ranking  mapped_ratings cat_ratings
0  excellent               5   excellent
1     failed               1      failed
2       good               4        good
3       good               4        good
4       good               4        good
5    failing               2     failing
6       good               4        good
7       fine               3        fine
8  excellent               5   excellent
9     failed               1      failed
```

While the new column "cat_ratings" may look identical to our original column, it is actually a Series of numbers similar to the "map_ratings" column (except this column ranges from 0-4 instead 1-5). If we want to do any operations with the underlying numbers, we can access the `codes` from the `.cat` accessor of our new column:

```
print(df["cat_ratings"].cat.codes)
0    4
1    0
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    1
6    3
7    2
8    4
9    0
dtype: int8
```

Now you can easily transform your data back and forth between their string representation and their numeric representation. While also gaining all of the performance benefits of operating on their numeric representation (mainly a smaller memory footprint). Also if we were to sort by this column, it will respect the order of categories that we inputted (since we supplied `order=True`). So categorical columns give you access to some neat features while keeping the best of both worlds imo.

See the pandas documentation on categorical data for more information:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html